# How to update in-memory variable in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Let's suppose I have a variable `var loli = [ { pop: true}, {pup: false } ]`.

Then, I have a route that makes something like this `loli.push(req.boy)` and another route that responds with the `loli` array, like this `res.json(loli)`.

I've searched some questions on Stack, Node Docs and could not figure out why.But my `res.json(loli)` is only sending the original array, even thought it has changed.

Hou can I watch for changes on this var or tell Node to not cache or do not do whatever it is doing?

Comment: It depends on where the variable is defined and how the functions have access to it - via scope or as an argument.  It's not possible to diagnose your problem without seeing how you are doing it.

Comment: Node doesn't preserve variable state between requests. Each time you hit the server, `loli` is reinitialized with whatever you have hardcoded as being assigned to it.

Comment: This isn't true if the variable is defined outside the request function

Comment: It would be tremendously helpful if you could show a minimal code example that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Yeah, I'm making assumptions. Should probably wait for some code.

Comment: This is a remake of [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33639397/how-to-send-a-consistent-json-object-response-on-node-to-angular). I think that the other one has become a little confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to say exactly what's wrong without seeing runnable code with the problem, but here's some code that does what you're asking. Fire it up, then go to http://localhost:3000/show to see the initial value of the object, then go to http://localhost:3000/push/foo to push the string value "foo" into the array, and go to http://localhost:3000/show again to see that it's there.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var loli = [ { pop: true}, {pup: false } ]

app.get('/push/:boy', function (req, res) {
  loli.push(req.params.boy);
  res.send('Pushed!');
});

app.get('/show', function (req, res) {
  res.json(loli);
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;

  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

Comment: Trying it now. Thanks for your answer.